# Visiting a cemetery in Nissan

Tags: halacha, cemetery-grave, nissan

I heard that there is a prohibition on visiting a cemetery in Nissan, especially in Chol HaMoed. Is this right?

Comment: https://www.5tjt.com/visiting-cemeteries-in-nissan/ https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/visiting-a-cemetery-in-the-month-of-nissan/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the opinions:

**Not allowed on Chodesh Nissan:** Kav Hayashar 88, Nitei Gavriel page 608 (if Yortzeit then allowed), Shu”t Melamed Lohil Chelek 2 Yoreah Deah Siman 145 (if he has a yahrzeit he allowed to), Moed Lechol Chai page 118 (in a case of tzorech its allowed)

**Allowed on Chodesh Nissan:** Shaar Hagilgulim Hakdama 38 (if you go it should be Erev Rosh Chodesh or 15th of the month), Gesher HaChaim page 307, Chaim Vechesed page 340, Shu”t Dvar Moshe Yoreah Deah Siman 18, Nefesh Kol Chai page 113, Rabbi Shalom Messas (Shemesh Umagen, vol. IV, Orah Haim, § 66), Orchot Rabbeinu 1:304, Aderet Tiferet Yoreah Deah Siman 53.

*Those who don't allow it during Chodesh Nissan, say that for Kivrei Tzadikim one would be allowed to.

*One should also not cry/wail and say tachanunim to cause sadness

See Aderet Tiferet Yoreah Deah Siman 53 for a bigger discussion